# Selecting specific properties from Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have the following Model:

```
   public class HelpApplication  {  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ApplicatonName { get; set; }     
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }  
    public bool Available { get; set; }
    public ICollection<HelpArea> HelpAreas { get; } = new List<HelpArea>();
}

public class HelpArea {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AreaName { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public virtual HelpApplication HelpApplication { get; set; }
    public ICollection<HelpTopic> HelpTopics { get; } = new List<HelpTopic>();
}

public class HelpTopic  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }

    public int AreaId { get; set; }
    public virtual HelpArea HelpArea { get; set; }

    public ICollection<HelpArticle> HelpArticles { get; } = new List<HelpArticle>();
}

 public class HelpArticle {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }
    public int HelpfulYes { get; set; }
    public int HelpfulNo { get; set; }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to use something like the query below, With `HelpArticles`, I need only 3 properties. I don't need to pull `Content`(A CLOB) all the time except when needed.

```
this.Entities
            .Include(h => h.HelpTopics)
            .ThenInclude(s => s.HelpArticles.Select(t => new { t.Title, t.Keywords, t.DisplayOrder} ))
            .Where(h => h.ApplicationId == appId).ToList();
```

The above query returns an exception:

> The property expression 's => {from HelpArticle t in s.HelpArticles select new <>f__AnonymousType12`3(Title = [t].Title, Keywords = [t].Keywords, DisplayOrder = [t].DisplayOrder)}' is not valid. 
>   The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.

I'll like to return the following :

all properties in **HelpApplication**;

**HelpTopic Collection**
Title,
DisplayOrder,
Available,

**HelpArticle Collection**
Title,
DisplayOrder,
Available,
Keywords

Comment: What do you want to return as result of the whole query execution?

Comment: question updated.

Comment: You cant do that. You need to create a proxy for HelpApplication and its child item types, and then project only the data you want to retrieve to those proxies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use an anonymous type in the `Include` method. You can reference the navigation property you want to pre-load but not the projection of the property into an anonymous type. If the problem is `Content` is to heavy to load and most of the time you don't need of it  you could map the  table into two differente entities `HelpArticle`  and `Content`  and navigate `HelpArticle.Content` to get the `Content` (lazy loaded in EF 6.1) when you need of it.  EF has got a feature called Table Splitting and as the name suggests, this allows  mapping (splitting) one database table to multiple classes in the conceptual model.